# github personal access token issues

Tags: github

I am trying to set up and use a GitHub personal access token.

I have followed https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token and have created the token.

I have looked at https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories#switching-remote-urls-from-ssh-to-https and I can https URLs returned when I run `git remote -v`

When I try and push I get a GitHub login prompt.

I close that and get an OpenSSH prompt.

I close that and type in my username and get another OpenSSH prompt for my password.

I close that and put in my personal access token and that still doesn't work.

According to the first link I should just be prompted for a username and token. Is there something else I need to do? I'm on Windows.

When I try on Linux (Ubuntu) I just a username and password prompt and the token works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows (with the latest [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)), and do see an HTTPS URL on `git remote -v`, then the prompt should not be an OpenSSH one.

Make sure your `git config credential.helper` is set to `manager-core`.

Then a git push should ask for your credentials, where you can use your token as password.

---

Or: the [OP tschumann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5158636/tschumann) makes it work by removing the credential helper.

To make sure there is no credentials cached though, I prefer:

- checking that `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core` is in my `%PATH%`
- double-check what is stored in the Windows Credential Manager

That is:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https"|git-credential-manager get
```

If you see the wrong password, remove it with

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https"|git-credential-manager erase
```

Repeat the erase command until you see a popup (do *not* enter your credentials)

Then do a `git push`, and enter your credentials to store them.

The [OP tschumann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5158636/tschumann) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68051054/github-personal-access-token-issues/68051708#comment120593525_68051708):

> `git config --global core.askPass ""` ended up fixing the issue

Comment: I fixed it by updating to the latest Git for Windows and selection no credential manager - I guess my installation was a little out of date. P.S. it should be git remote not git remove in your answer.

Comment: @tschumann OK. I have fixed the typo, but also edited the answer to include a way to remove any old credential, before storing the new one.

Comment: I think I need to do some more digging - I could pull okay but pushing kept prompting me with the same as before.

Comment: @tschumann Make sure to set your `credential.helper` to `manager-core`: you will be able to cache your credentials then.

Comment: It's set to manager-core and I have no cached credentials but now I get an OpenSSH prompt by default. If I dismiss it then my username and access token work.

Comment: @tschumann What do you see when you type `git remote -v` in your repo folder?

Comment: I see origin  https://github.com/name/project.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/name/project.git (push)

Comment: @tschumann Since you are on Linux (I mean true Linux, not WSL on Windows), can you try and check that you have: the latest Git, the latest Git Credential Manager Core, and that the additional configuration has been done: https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/docs/linuxcredstores.md (chose for instance `git config --global credential.credentialStore secretservice`, assuming you have a graphical user interface session)

Comment: git config --global core.askPass "" ended up fixing the issue.

Comment: @tschumann Perfect. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.